# Matlab only using half of each core

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing

I am running a matlab code on a 4 core computer. I am using a `parfor` command so as expected matlab is using the 4 cores to run it.

However, when I go to task manager I see that only half of each core is used - i.e. in total only 50% of CPU is taken by matlab.

Is there any reason why matlab is not using the full 100%?

I am not sure whether this is the appropriate forum for this question. If not, please let me know.

Thanks,
V

Comment: If 100% of all the cores are used by Matlab, who runs the OS? or the web browser window with stackoverflow while the program runs?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I understand that, but still couldn't they reach 80% or so?

Comment: High Performance Mark gave you the answer to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you have hyperthreading turned on. Then Windows will see things as if there are 8 cores rather than 4. If you turn hyperthreading off, I would bet that you'll see it rising to 100%.

MATLAB doesn't really benefit from hyperthreading in any case (in fact there may even be a very small reduction in performance), so if your concern is to maximise MATLAB performance you may as well turn it off. Of course, other applications (such as Outlook or Word) that do benefit from hyperthreading may suffer if you do that.

There are other possibilities - for example, something other than CPU (such as file I/O, memory) may be the bottleneck in your application - but if you're seeing a consistent 50% usage, I would bet that hyperthreading is the reason.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it must be it. What's the best way to disable hyperthreading? Do I need to go into the system BIOS?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to reboot, go into the BIOS settings, make the change, and restart. Further details would depend on your system.